# Show that a quotient group is cyclic

Tags: group-theory

This is part of an assignment, so please no full answers just hints (c:

Let $a=(1234)$, $b=(13)(5678)$, $G=\langle a,b\rangle$.
Show that the quotient group $G/\langle a\rangle$ is cyclic

I found 4 left cosets, so $|G/\langle a\rangle|=4$. These are:

$\langle a\rangle = \{(1234), (13)(24), (1432), e\}$

$(57)(68)\langle a\rangle = \{(1234)(57)(68),(13)(24)(57)(68),(1432)(57)(68),(57)(68)\}$

$(13)(5678)\langle a\rangle=\{(12)(34)(5678), (24)(5678), (14)(23)(5678), (13)(5678)\}$

$(13)(5876)\langle a\rangle=\{(12)(34)(5876), (24)(5876), (14)(23)(5876), (13)(5876)\}$

I know $\langle a\rangle$ is a normal subgroup of G... but I still don't know how to actually answer the question (ie. show that this quotient group is cyclic). I guess the problem is that I don't quite understand this type of group... I thought I could show that it's cyclic by finding an element $g \in G/\langle a\rangle$ so that $g^4 = e$... but the identity is $\langle a\rangle$... I'm a bit lost...

Thanks!

Comment: Probably not helpful, but it turns out that this is always true when $G = \langle a,b \rangle$ and $H := \langle a \rangle$ is a normal subgroup. One of the cosets you wrote down is $bH$. In this general situation, try to show that $bH$ generates $G/H$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

The last two elements $(1\,3)(5\,6\,7\,8)\langle a\rangle$ and $(1\,3)(5\,8\,7\,6)\langle a\rangle$ have order $4$.

Comment: But how do you know this by just looking at them?
Is it correct to say $((13)(5678)\langle a \rangle)^4 = ((13)(5678))^4\langle a \rangle^4 = ()\langle a \rangle^4$, and this is why the order of this group is 4?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but more precisely this says only that the order is a divisor of $4$, and you have to check it is not $2$,  i.e. that $\;(1\,3)^2(5\,6\,7\,8)^2=(5\,7)(6\,8)$ is not in $\langle a\rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that there are two groups of order 4: $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$. The former is characterized by the property that the square of any element is the identity.

Can you use this (and your computation of $G/\langle a \rangle$) to rule out the possibility that $G/\langle a \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the order of a element of $G/<a>$ must divides the order of the group, then if $x \in G/<a>$, $x \not= e$ and $x^{2} \not= e$ then the order of $x$ must be $4$

so it will be enough to see that some element $\not= e$ has no order 2

Comment: This doesn't show that it is cyclic.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, i changed the answer, I hope help you